# Symmetry of Laplace operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, laplacian, unbounded-operators

Good evening, I have a question regarding the proof of the symmetry property of Laplace operator. It's a well known fact that $-\Delta$ is an unbounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and it is densely defined with domain $D(-\Delta)=\{f\in L^2:-\Delta f\in L^2\}$. I want to prove that $-\Delta$ is symmetric. It is clear that $\forall f\in\mathcal{S}'$ and $\forall g\in \mathcal{S}$ (here $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the space of Schwartz functions),
\begin{equation}
\langle-\Delta f,g\rangle=\langle f,-\Delta g\rangle
\end{equation}
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the duality pairing $\mathcal{S}'$ / $\mathcal{S}$. Thus, the identity holds whenever $f\in D(-\Delta)$ and $\forall g\in\mathcal{S}$, since $D(-\Delta)\subseteq\mathcal{S}'$. In this case,
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta f,g)_2=(f,-\Delta g)_2 \ \ \ \forall f\in D(-\Delta),g\in\mathcal{S}.
\end{equation}
The question is: how do I extend the relation to $g\in D(-\Delta)$? Every text I find claims that it comes from the density of $\mathcal{S}$ in $D(-\Delta)$, but $-\Delta$ in unbounded, so how do I use the density argument here if I can't pass the limit through $-\Delta$? I mean, if $g\in D(-\Delta)$, then I can take a sequence $(g_k)_k\subset\mathcal{S}$ s.t. $\Vert g-g_k\Vert_{L^2}\rightarrow0$. However,
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta f,g)_{L^2}=\lim_{k}(-\Delta f,g_k)_{L^2}=\lim_k(f,-\Delta g_k)_{L^2}=(f,-\lim_k\Delta g_k)_{L^2}\underset{why?}{=}(f,-\Delta \lim_k g_k)_{L^2}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Schwartz functions are dense in $D(\Delta)$ not only in $L^2$-norm, but also in the *graph-norm* $\Vert f \Vert_{D(\Delta)} = \Vert f \Vert_{L^2} + \Vert \Delta f \Vert_{L^2}$. To see this you can identify (via the Fourier transform) the Hilbert space $(D(\Delta),\Vert \cdot \Vert_{D(\Delta)})$ as Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for which you probably know this density result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more thing: do you know if a similar result holds also for the Hermite operator $H=-\Delta+|x|^2$? It is a densely defined operator on $L^2$ as well, but $D(H)$ is not $H^2$ actually.